# Webscraping CrunchBase Access Denied while using User Agent Header

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, wget

I am trying to webscrape Crunch Base to find the total funding amount for certain companies. [Here is a link](https://www.crunchbase.com/organization/incube-labs) to an example.

At first, I tried just using beautiful soup but I keep getting an error saying:

> Access to this page has been denied because we believe you are using automation tools to browse the\nwebsite.

So then I looked up how to fake a browser visit and I changed my code, but I still get the same error. What am I doing wrong??

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS


url = 'https://www.crunchbase.com/organization/incube-labs'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(response.content)
```

Comment: There are several options available for websites to determine whether you're actually browsing the site or using a scraper, and you've run into one of them.  You could try emulating an actual browser session to look even more look a real user (think modules like selenium) or further investigate the HTTP headers sent along in the request when you do it in a browser (like you did with the user agent - just extend that idea out) and keep including them until you don't get the complaint anymore.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All in all your code looks great! It appears that the website you are trying to scrape requires a more complex header than the one you have. The following code should solve your issue:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS


url = 'https://www.crunchbase.com/organization/incube-labs'
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0", "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8", "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5", "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", "DNT": "1", "Connection": "close", "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1"}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(response.content)
```